# Why is a $n \times n$=M matrix only invertible if $M \vec x$ = $\vec c$ has a unique solution?

Tags: linear-algebra

I heard this in class but I don’t really get why.

Comment: Hint: How many pivots are there when you have a unique solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about it: if $M\vec x = \vec c$ has multiple solutions, then what would  $M^{-1}\vec c$ be?

In general, if a function (or transformation defined by a matrix) is not one-to-one, it cannot be invertible.

This is analogous to how $f(x)=x^2$ is not invertible since $f(2)=4=f(-2)$, and therefore we cannot make sense of $f^{-1}(4)$.

---

This is just one way to look at it. Perhaps a more "linear algebra" way is that if $Mx=My$ with $x\neq y$, then $M(x-y)=0$, so $0\ne x-y\in\ker M$, and therefore by the [dimension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) $M$ does not have full rank, i.e., it cannot be invertible.

Answer (score 1):

If $M$ is an invertible $n\times n$ matrix, then $M^{-1} M\vec x=M^{-1}\vec c$, so for any $\vec c$ we have the solution $\vec x=M^{-1}\vec c$.

On the other hand, suppose $M\vec x=\vec c$ has a solution for all $\vec c$. Then in particular, it has a solution for $M\vec x=e_i$, where $vec e_i$ is the $i$-th basis vector

$$\vec e_i=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

Let $\vec x_i$ be the solution such that $M\vec x_i=\vec e_i$. Then form the matrix $N$ where $\vec x_i$ is the $i$-th column. Now you can verify that $N$ is the inverse of $M$.